# what is meaing of this specified constraint

Tags: c, uri

Read an integer value corresponding to a person's age (in days) and print it in years, months and days, followed by its respective message “ano(s)”, “mes(es)”, “dia(s)”.

Note: only to facilitate the calculation, consider the whole year with 365 days and 30 days every month.

**(((In the cases of test there will never a situation that allows 12 months and some days, like 360, 363 or 364. This is just an exercise for the purpose of testing simple mathematical reasoning.
)))**
what is the meaning  of this

Input
The input file contains 1 integer value.

Output
Print the output, like the following example.

Comment: This, as most questions which give the strong impression of being a blind homework dump, is too broad to be answered.

Comment: It is not a "constraint". You are told to read a file which contains on integer value, a number of days which you should convert to years, months, days, and print the result. For example if the input value is 366 the output would be `1 year, 0 months, 1 day`. **360** etc will not occur as a remainder, because of the contrivance of 30 days per month (30 * 12 = 360).

Comment: I interpret the question as asking what the bold text means.  It is a constraint on the input.

Comment: @weather: if I'm understanding correctly, `1 año, 0 meses, 1 día` except without the diacritics (my sense of decency insists on "año".) But you're absolutely right that it's not a constraint.

Comment: @rici I skipped commenting about the natural language used, but it looks as if plurals should be correctly used. That's no more tricky than using the correct number of days per month (assuming no leap year).

Comment: @weather: yup. And perhaps it's PT, not ES.

Comment: how i handle this .input won't be >360 &&<364

Answer (score 1):

> In the cases of test there will never a situation that allows 12 months and some days, like 360, 363 or 364. This is just an exercise for the purpose of testing simple mathematical reasoning.

This is a constraint on the input.  It means that you won't be given inputs like 360 or 716 (which is 365 + 360).  Or any number N*365 + 360.  Or N*365 + 361, etc. (up to 364). It's just to keep the math simple for you so you don't have to deal with more than 11 months in addition to the number of years.

359 would be valid input, yielding 0 years, 11 months, and 29 days.

Comment: If only real date/time computations could be that straightforward.

Comment: @JohnBode No kidding!  That's why we have libraries for this kind of thing, and it's still easy to bollix it up.  https://xkcd.com/1883/

Comment: how should i handle this or input must not contain numbers like 360

Comment: @JeffLearman: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) is my favorite rant so far on datetime calculations.

Comment: @ahmedramadan - the constraint on the input means you can ignore the special cases: they won't happen. Just do the obvious calculation: divide days by 365 to get years, divide the remainder of that by 30 to get months, take the remainder of that as days

Answer (score 0):

If the remainder when divided by 365 is **360** thru **364** days, that would be in month 13 (if 30 days per month).

The **bold text** is a *guarantee* that you won't be given a number with that result.